# Crawler doesn't run because of error in htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a web crawler in which a user writes a websites.txt and the Python code enters and catches URLs  one by one and gets the page titles!

```
import urllib.request
import re

i=0

regex = "<title>(.+?)</title>"
pattern = re.compile(regex)

txtfl = open('websites.txt')
webpgsinfile = txtfl.readlines()
urls = webpgsinfile

while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    print(htmltext)
    titles = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print(titles)
    i+=1
```

But I'm having this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vinicius\Documents\GitHub\python-crawler\scrapper-2-0.py", line 17, in <module>
    titles = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 201, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 3):

Either decode the downloaded HTML to unicode text, or use a `b'...'` bytes regular expression:

```
regex = b"<title>(.+?)</title>"
```

or:

```
htmltext = htmlfile.read().decode(htmlfile.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8'))
```

However, you are using a regular expression, and matching HTML with such expressions get too complicated, too fast.

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from. I recommend you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a popular 3rd party library.

BeautifulSoup example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding=response.info().get_param('charset'))
title = soup.find('title').text
```

Since a `title` tag itself doesn't contain other tags, you can get away with a regular expression here, but as soon as you try to parse nested tags, you *will* run into hugely complex issues.

Comment: Martijn i'm working with python 3.3 and i dont want to have another library in my codes!